# Format Created Date and Modified Date Columns to Display Normal Time

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have a PowerShell script that outputs to CSV all items and files from all Lists and Libraries below:

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Depts/HTG"
foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {


foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach($version in $item.Versions){
$data = @{
"Version" = $version.VersionLabel
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
}
New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
}
}
$web.Dispose();
}
}



Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\NewOutput.csv
```

Below is a sample output of the script:

[image]

The problem is for columns Created Date and Modified Date it outputs the time as military time. I need it to ouput to normal time and displays whether it is a.m. or p.m. Can someone assist in what to add to the script to make it work?

Comment: Small nitpick, that's 24 hour clock, not military.  The difference is the colon between hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line from:

```
"Created Date" = $item["Created"]
```

To:

```
 "Created Date" = ($item["Created"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
```

I don't have SharePoint handy but I was able to convert the date format from 14:29 to 2:29 PM using this same code here.

#### Better answer

Rarely is a better answer both easier to read and more technically accurate.  This is one of those times.

```
"Created Date" = Get-date -Date $item["Created"] -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y %I:%m %PM"
```

This returns the time in this format:   `09/09/2013 02:09 PM`, using Get-Date's -Uformat parameter, which allows you to use Unix time specifiers.  [Here's a full list.](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html#format)

Comment: This may be converting the value to a string instead of a DateTime object.  Better to convert when displayed.

Also, this is dependent upon your settings in the session where the console is run.  If your workstation is set to 24hr time, the result of your code will be 14:29.

Comment: It works! The date outputs from the old 9/9/13 14:26 to Monday, September 09, 2013 2:26 PM. Question is how can I format only the time to 2:26 PM and still keeping the date format as 9/9/13? Sorry not trying to be picky but this is just something I know that users will say something about. Please advise

Comment: Added a more perfect answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you output it, you can use .Net dateTime object methods to display the date/time however you want.  There are built-in and custom ways of doing so.

Here's a Technet [tip of the week:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)  `$date = Get-Date` uses `System.DateTime` object type.  Access formatting with the cmdlet using the `-Format` parameter, or through the object using properties and methods.

Comment: Two custom date/time examples: `$date = get-date -Format "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm tt"` 
# Oct 27, 2015 14:40 PM 

`$date = get-date -Format "yyyyMMdd.HHmmss"` 
# 20151027.144108